# Changing the padding for Dojo ToolTipDialog

Tags: javascript, css, padding, dojo

I couldn't find an answer anywhere on the Web, so I'm going to answer my own question: **How do I override the internal padding of the TooltipDialog popup?**

**The challenge:**
When using dijit.TooltipDialog there is internal padding of *6px 8px 8px 6px* assigned to the class *dijitTooltipContainer* from the Claro style sheet. I use several tooltips on the same page, and only wanted to remove this padding from one (thus, didn't want to override the default stylesheet). This particular ToolTip contains a stylized unordered list of of right justified numbers from 0-100 in increments of 5, and the extra padding from *dijitTooltipContainer* was far too much.

Unfortunately, the following doesn't work, only affecting the parent element (and making a mess of it at that):

```
var dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
        content: string,
        style: "padding: 0;",
        id: "newDialog"
    },"");
```

**The answer:** Here's how I changed the internal padding to 0 (using JavaScript):

```
// Create the ToolTip
var dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
        content: string,
        id: "newDialog"
    },"");

// Open the popup
dijit.popup.open({
    around: "someNode",
    orient: ["below"],
    popup: dialog
});

// Remove the padding from dijitTooltipContainer
  // Get our main Widget node
  var mainNode = document.getElementById("newDialog");

  // Get all the child DIV nodes created by Dojo
  var divChildren = mainNode.getElementsByTagName("div");

  // Set the element padding to zero
  // dijitTooltipContainer is the first child node
  dojo.attr(divChildren[0], "style", {padding: "0px"});
```

Maybe someone else has a better way of doing this that is so obvious, I couldn't find it. Hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I work with Dojo, I setup a custom theme and use both the claro (or any other that is shipped) and my custom theme.  I then setup any of these overrides in my custom theme.

```
<body class="claro myTheme">
```

So if I wanted to override all tooltips, I could have this in my css

```
.myTheme .dijitTooltipContainer {
    padding: 0;
}
```

But you only want to override one, so you could do this

```
// Create the ToolTip
var dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
    content: string,
    id: "newDialog"
},"");
dojo.addClass(dialog.domNode, 'noPadding');
```

and the css

```
.myTheme .noPadding .dijitTooltipContainer {
    padding: 0;
}
```